Passing an array of objects from C# to VBA Excel
I have a C# console application and Dll. I registered the dll as COM via interop. I used the

COM Visible property, GUID etc
Set Assembly Information, Build information to register it to COM

I referenced this dll in the VBA code.
I created a list of objects for that class in the console application, converted it to Array and then used Excel.Run to send the array of user defined objects to VBA code.
I can access properties of the array in VBA like LBound and UBound. But I am unable to access each individual object in the array.
The C# code is as follows:
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Save_as_excel_classes
{
    [Guid("0BA8F8DE-8F0A-4D7E-9DDB-8AED42943BDA")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    public class CollClass
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public string NameValue { get; set; }
    }
}

The Console App is as follows:
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Save_as_excel_classes;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using _Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application excel = new _Excel.Application();
            try
            {
                string fileName = "D:\\Book2.xlsm";
                Workbook wb;
                Worksheet ws;
                int sheetNumber = 1;
                excel.Visible = true;
                wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
                ws = wb.Worksheets[sheetNumber];
                ws = wb.Worksheets[sheetNumber];
              
                var collVals = new List<CollClass>();
                
                collVals.Add(new CollClass() { NameValue = "ABC" });
                collVals.Add(new CollClass() { NameValue = "DEF" });
                collVals.Add(new CollClass() { NameValue = "GHI" });
                collVals.Add(new CollClass() { NameValue = "KLM" });
                CollClass[] arr = collVals.ToArray();
                excel.Run("ThisWorkbook.GetListofObjects1", arr);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                excel.Quit();
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excel);
            }
        }
    }
}

The VBA side looks like this: I am just trying to set the NameValue to a cell.
Public Function GetListofObjects1(ByRef objColl() As collClass)
    MsgBox "Inside GetListofObjects function" + " Hurray!"
    Range("C3").Value = LBound(objColl)
    Range("C4").Value = UBound(objColl)
    Range("C5").Value = objColl(0).NameValue
End Function

I've searched various questions on StackOverflow and forums but I don't know what I am doing wrong. Every time I run the console application, Excel opens, I get the message box and then crashes and restarts. I also get the exception in the c# console application as follows after the LBound line and the UBound line execute. This only happens for the Range("C5").Value = objColl(0).NameValue
"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))'"
I get the proper NameValue when I send a single object instead of an array. It's just with the array that all the problems seem to occur.
This probably has a very simple solution but I've been at this for over a day and a half now and I can't seem to figure it out.
Edit:
I added another class CollClassArray to the dll that will just contain the one CollClass array. When I pass the object of CollClassArray through the Run command and try to access the array inside it I get the error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid use of property near the CollArray(0).
Public Function GetListOfObjects1(array as CollClassArray)
Dim objColl as CollClass
Set objColl = array.CollArray(0).NameValue
End Function


It probably has to do with excel.Run. Can you call ThisWorkbook.GetListofObjects1 directly?

I don't think I understand. Do you mean call it in the vba code from another function to test if it works, I mean?

No, I mean if you put your workbook reference in a dynamic variable and call it directly as wb.GetListofObjects1.

When I tried it the way you mentioned, it doesn't even get to the UBound line. The program hangs for a second and then I get the exception
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)'. A quick google search says something might be wrong with the third party COM component(the dll we have here) but it seems be working fine...

Quote: This means that you cannot pass objects to macros by using the Run method.  You'll have to do this differently, consider making a call in the VBA to retrieve the data.

@HansPassant, I was able to pass a single object with no issues. So, what you mentioned might be why that works but not an array. I will try to retrieve the array through the dll itself with a VBA call as you mentioned and update the question if it works. Thanks a lot!

I also saw this post in the beginning where the OP was able to send the object array and view them(although they hadn't tried printing or try any other kind of manipulation into the excel sheet itself and had a different issue)

Have you tried using that ArrayList too?

I tried again with ArrayList, set it to a temp CollClass and it worked. The code worked after I rewrote most of the function and tried again. It worked. Thank you for your help.

After researching a bit more, I added mscorlib as a reference in the VBA code. I used the mscorlib.ArrayList and was able to access the elements in the ArrayList.
c# code: with ArrayList
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     Application excel = new _Excel.Application();
     try
     {
         string fileName = "D:\\Book2.xlsm";
         dynamic wb;
         Worksheet ws;
         int sheetNumber = 1;
         excel.Visible = true;
         wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
         ws = wb.Worksheets[sheetNumber];
         
         var collVals = new List<CollClass>();
         
         collVals.Add(new CollClass() { NameValue = "ABC", NumberValue = 2 });
         collVals.Add(new CollClass() { NameValue = "DEF", NumberValue = 4 });
         collVals.Add(new CollClass() { NameValue = "GHI", NumberValue = 6 });
         collVals.Add(new CollClass() { NameValue = "KLM", NumberValue = 8 });
         CollClass[] arr = collVals.ToArray();

        
         ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
         list.AddRange(arr);
         excel.Run("ThisWorkbook.SetC5", list);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {

     }
     finally
     {
         
         excel.Quit();
         System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
         System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excel);
     }
 }

VBA code:
Public Function setC5(coll As mscorlib.ArrayList)
    MsgBox "Inside this function"
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim coll2(), coll1 As collClass
    Dim number As Integer
    number = coll.count
    Range("C6") = number
    Set coll1 = coll(0)
    Range("C5").Value = coll1.NameValue
End Function

